# How to reorganize a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What would be the process for getting this data organized so the years would be listed along the left, the country names along the top, and the values filling out the table?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) , also Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: look into `pd.crosstab` or `pd.pivot` or `pd.groupby` + `unstack` : `pd.crosstab(df['Year'], df['Country Name'], df['Values'], aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: `pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Value', index='Year', columns = 'Country Name')`